# internal bluetooth is not working -plug in a dongle to use bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I think I tried almost everything there in web to figure out how to fix it.

it's was working fine, and suddenly stooped working giving that this error in settings "plug in a dongle to use bluetooth". it's working fine in windows

I tried to reinstall bluetooth, install blueman, restart bluetooth and nothing.

when I enter "rfkill list all" I get:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LA
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

the Bluetooth doesn't appear.

when I enter "sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status", I get:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-07-18 14:05:09 IDT; 14min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1377 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1377 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 18 14:05:09 ofiryaish-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth servi…...
Jul 18 14:05:09 ofiryaish-Inspiron-5559 bluetoothd[1377]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Jul 18 14:05:09 ofiryaish-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 18 14:05:09 ofiryaish-Inspiron-5559 bluetoothd[1377]: Starting SDP server
Jul 18 14:05:09 ofiryaish-Inspiron-5559 bluetoothd[1377]: Bluetooth managemen…ed
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

When I enter "lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'", I get:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:06b2]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:920b Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04d9:1603 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.028000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.092456] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.684754] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.684759] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    3.651936] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.651951] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.651956] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.651958] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.651965] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.755926] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    3.784583] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.948900127.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.959379] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.959380] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.959383] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Does it help if you remove and reinsert the dongle?

Comment: @mook765, 
I updated it. it's an internal Bluetooth in the laptop.